# LocalStorage within Angular Application not working as intended

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage

In my Angular application. I have an array which is getting objects pushed to it from an rest api. The array is called `playlist=[]` and it is being shared across the components with a service called playlist service. Also within this service are two functions. One to save the playlist to `localStorage` and one to get it from `localStorage`. So what is happening is when I save the playlist, it saves to local storage fine. Even if I refresh they still are in the localstorage. So when I use my app in a single session (not refreshing the browser) the `savePlaylist()` method adds objects to the playlist array, it does not overwrite them (So that is fine). However if I refresh the page add items and then save - the items are overwritten, when they should be added to the localstorage ones that are already there saved. Is this possible? Is this to do with sessionStorage? Any Ideas? My code so far is:

**playlist.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PlaylistService {

  public playlist = [];

  getPlaylist() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('playlist') == null) {
      this.playlist = [];
    } else {
      this.playlist = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('playlist'));

    }
  }

  savePlaylist() {
    // first save the data
    localStorage.setItem('playlist', JSON.stringify(this.playlist));
    // get what is saved afterwords
    this.playlist = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('playlist'));
    console.log('Saved', this.playlist);
}

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

**playlist.ts** (Where it should show the save playlist)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PlaylistService } from '../../../services/playlist.service';
import { faSave } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-playlist-view',
  templateUrl: './playlist-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./playlist-view.component.scss']
})
export class PlaylistViewComponent implements OnInit {

  faSave = faSave;

  constructor(private list: PlaylistService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.list.getPlaylist();
  }
}
```

**playlist.html**

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="container">
  <table class="table mt-3 mb-3">
    <thead class="thead-light">
      <tr>
        <th>Artwork</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Genre</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let user of list.playlist">
        <td><img src="{{user.artworkUrl60}}"></td>
        <td>{{user.artistName}}</td>
        <td>{{user.collectionName}}</td>
        <td>{{user.primaryGenreName}}</td>
        <td>{{user.collectionPrice}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Comment: LocalStorage is just a glorified dictionary. You get an object at a key, and you set an object at a key.

You're using the same key, so every call to set overwrites the previous value at your 'playlist' key.

If you want to do this, you must merge the previous value with the current value, and then set it again.

Comment: And you've verified that `getPlaylist()` is called and works as it should?

Comment: Declare some variable then assign data to variable . You can't display private constructor value.

Comment: Do any of you have a code sample of what you mean? i.e merging the previous value?

Comment: How do you add to the playlist? The code should work assuming you are pushing to the list correctly.

Comment: @DanielB it does work, but it seems I am not merging previous localStorage value with the new one

Comment: I made a quick working example in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m9pm1b). Have a look and see if you can figure it out!

Comment: Code looks similar to mine, I can't see where the problem is?

Comment: Do I need to push the object to the array and then save in the same function? 

`this.playlistService.playlist.push({ name: this.newName })`

Comment: Nothing in your question seems to indicate the behavior you are seeing.  How do you add new items to your playlist?  When are you calling savePlaylist?  Here is a working stack blitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mbwfjn